# Override method in case object without changing fields

Tags: scala, case-class, overriding

```
case class A(a:Int, b:Int) {
  def f(){println(a)}
}
val o1 = A(3,3)

val o2 = new A(o1.a,o1.b) {override def f(){println(b)}}  //too long when there are a lot of parameters
```

Here I have to pass o1 parameters to o2, but in real life I have much more parameters. I know that I can copy case object like this

```
 o2 = o1.copy
```

Is there any way to combine copy with overriding method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether there is an easy way to combine `copy` with overriding. However as an alternative you can consider overloading your case class constructor (to take case class object), as shown below:

```
case class A(x: Int, y: String) {

  def this(a : A) = this(a.x, a.y)

  def f() { println(x)}
}
```

Then, you can create `A` object instances (with overriding) by passing only 1 parameter:

```
val o1 = A(30, "Test")
val o2 = new A(o1) { override def f() { println(y)} }
```

Obviously this doesn't resolve the long parameters issue completely as you'd still need to list them when defining the constructor. Though if you're after multiple `A` objects with different behaviours, it should be a big improvement over specifying the full list every time.

Comment: Why I can't use copy in the constructor to return copy of a?

Comment: That's a Scala requirement. As per 'Programming in Scala': 
`In Scala, every auxiliary constructor must inkove another contructor of the same class as its first action. The net effect of this rule is that every constructor invocation in Scala will end up eventually calling the primary constructor of the class. The primary constructor is thus the single point of entry of a class.` See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426146/constructors-in-scala-primary-auxiliary-default-primary for more details.